# Can't return the iterator from es6 Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6, iterator

I've looked at similar questions and got this far, but I
still cannot seem to do implement the iterator method 
for the following class.

```
class RelationshipCollection {

  constructor(){
    this._relationships = [];


  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this._relationships[Symbol.iterator]();
  }
}
```

When I run

```
   let collection = new RelationshipCollection();
   collection.forEach(e => {
      console.log('hello');
   })
```

The error I get is

> forEach is not a function

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Implementing the iterator does not inherently implement the `forEach` method. It will, however, let you use `for...of...`, so try `for (let e of collection) { console.log('hello', e); }` instead.

Comment: Thanks man, your correct.

Comment: I've added it as an answer below; feel free to accept it if it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing the iterator does not inherently implement the `forEach` method. It will, however, let you use `for...of...`, so try `for (let e of collection) { console.log('hello', e); }` instead.

Alternatively, you can explicitly implement your own forEach method on the class if you prefer to use that syntax.